# How to type F5 to refresh a page using Playwright Python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to refresh a webpage using F5 key. I know I can use:

```
self.page.reload()
```

But this is not a good solution for my problem. How to make the page to be refreshed using the `F5` key? My code doesn't refresh the page and I don't know why.

```
self.page.keyboard.press('F5')
```

Comment: Why isn't `page.reload()` a good solution? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: It was not enough with the Javascript reload simulation, isn't it?

Comment: @JakyRuby No, I wanna do it purely with Python.

Comment: Have you tried using 'ctrl+r'? it does the same as F5

Comment: @VincentCasey Sure I have, it just doesn't work...

Comment: @TalAngel Have you considered it being an issue with the browser or the program not entering the browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, playwright uses a virtual keyboard and does not exactly send the same signal as a real keyboard to the browser application.

consider going native and using something closer to kernel like `pyautogui`, after you've focused you window:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('f5')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said we have `page.keyboard.press('F5')`. But it does not do what you want, I've tried several other examples but nothing.

Maybe this is enough for you?

```
page.evaluate('window.location.reload();')
```

Or

```
page.evaluate('location.reload();')
```

As you can see we are forcing the reload by evaluating a javascript.

Yes...it is a little bit tricky, so probably you will need to even force a `time.sleep(2)` after that, and trust me, I hate `time.sleep()` but this is an special situation.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it a bit slower like a human does by injecting delay parameter as follows:

```
self.page.keyboard.press('F5',delay=100)
```

**Update!**

`keyboard.press('F5' with page.reload()` method is really refreshing the browsed page. You can try whether it works or not.

You can justify the below real example:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False,slow_mo=1000)
    context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080})
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/word')
  
    page.keyboard.press('F5',delay=1000)
    page.reload()
```

[playwright-python doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxJI1.png)